# Express Router causing XHR onreadystate 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Express and trying to create a login authentication system. But I'm having issues getting XHR to show a ready state 4. It was working fine until I added express.Router which I saw in a [GitHub project](https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/React-Express-Examples/tree/master/auth).

These are my relevant bits of code:

```js
// server.js

const userAuth = require("./auth");
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/auth", userAuth);

// ./auth/index.js

const router = require("express").Router();
const userLogin = require("./userLogin");
const userRegister = require("./userRegister");
router.post("/login", userLogin);
router.post("/register", userRegister);
module.exports = router;

// ./auth/userLogin.js

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log(username, password);
    res.status(200).send("hello");
};

// client side

const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("post", "https://example.com/auth/login");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (!(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200)) {
    console.error("Could not submit form.");
    console.log(http.responseText);
  }
};
http.send(JSON.stringify({ username, password }));
```

The chrome console shows "State 2", then "State 3" plus the "hello" response. But there is no "State 4"?
The code is pretty much identical to the linked Github project (theirs have async in userLogin.js but I've tried that too).

Any help/tips much appreciated!

Comment: use an anonimous function e.g function x rather than an arrow function inside your onreadystatechange method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your onreadystatechange method to this and it will work:

```
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
  // rest of your code
}
```

This is a template you can refer back to if needed:

```
 const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http.open("post", "https://example.com/auth/login");
 http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 http.onreadystatechange = function () {  // change this line
  if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
    console.log(http.responseText);
  }
  else {
    console.error("Error in submitting or receiving response.");
  }
};
http.send(JSON.stringify({ username, password }));
```

if this answer helps solving the issue, **consider** accepting the answer or upvoting it. Thank you.

Comment: He uses the arrow function syntax, the issue is clearly not coming from this.

Comment: but if you are **NOT** using the arrow function does the issue get resolved **?** Why you are saying the issue is not clearly this, because of some tutorials taken from github? I do this day-in day-out and when using the XHTTP Object with arrow functions I run into unexpected results **all the time**. See Mozilla as an [**authoritative resource** here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)